# Does minecraft pe have all the features of PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am thinking of getting minecraft on the iPad. Is it like the ps3/xbox, is it like PC
or is it it's own thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. Minecraft Pocket Edition is its own thing, with *some* of the features of the PC version of Minecraft (but not all of them). You can look at a list of some of the features on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition).

Comment: I would change *some* to *many* or *most*, due to the recent 0.9.0 update.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms I have to disagree,  the amount of content in the PC version will never be matched on a mobile platform.  I think 'some'  sums it up pretty well.

Comment: @Caleb Fair enough... Maybe *quite a few*?